# Pandas 0.25.0: groupby on categoricals

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some difficulties on using Pandas 0.25.0, which is released last month.

Consider this date frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], dtype='category'),
    'B': pd.Series(['m', 'o', 'o', 'o']),
    'C': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]),
})
```

Say we want to groupby on the first two columns. The resulting data frame should contain 3 rows, since the combination `b` `m` doesn't exist.

```py
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C': 'sum'})
```

In Pandas 0.24.1 and earlier, this works fine:

```py
     C
A B   
a m  1
  o  4
b o  5
```

However, in Pandas 0.25.0 this is broken:

```py
       C
A B     
a m  1.0
  o  4.0
b m  NaN
  o  5.0
```

I know I can suppress this unwanted behaviour by adding `observed=True` to the groupby call, but that was not neccessary in the old version. I cannot find anything related in the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html).

How come? Is this a bug in pandas? Did I miss something?

Comment: There's a line in the release for 0.25 under [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-resample-rolling)  "Bug in Series.groupby() where observed kwarg was previously ignored [(GH24880)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24880)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment of ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559298/pandas-0-25-0-groupby-on-categoricals#comment101580688_57559298) I think I know what happend:

I (unknowingly) relied on a bug in 0.24, and that is why the update to 0.25 broke my code.