# pandas groupby and transform to median gives NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I faced a weird situation with latest version of pandas **(0.25.3)**. I will try to explain it with an example.

This is my example dataframe

```
x = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], 'col2': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'w'], 'col3': [1.2, 2.4, 3.5, 4.1]}
```

Now grouping and transforming it to *[median/mean]* gives following results which is correct

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('median')

0    2.65
1    2.40
2    3.50
3    2.65
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

**BUT**, when I converted the column data type to category and applied the same, I get `NaN` values

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('category')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('category')

df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('median')

0    2.65
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    2.65
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

This thing works perfectly fine

- if there is only one column is used in groupby
- if `count` is used instead of `mean/median`
- with pandas version **0.24.2**

It seems that this might be a bug. Can someone confirm, so that it can be reported **OR** correct me if I am doing something wrong.

**PS:** I found this when I was working on DataFrame having a lot of categorical columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue aligning the result back due to the treatment of `unobserved` categories. We can fix this with `observed=True`

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], observed=True)['col3'].transform('median')
0    2.65
1    2.40
2    3.50
3    2.65
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

---

Without categories, the output of a `groupby` is:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].median()
#col1  col2
#a     w       2.65
#b     x       2.40
#c     y       3.50
#Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

Once they become categories, the result displays `NaN` for all categories, even if they are not observed. The `median` is properly calcualted for all groups, but not broadcasted back properly:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('category')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('category')

df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].median()
#col1  col2
#a     w       2.65
#      x        NaN
#      y        NaN
#b     w        NaN
#      x       2.40
#      y        NaN
#c     w        NaN
#      x        NaN
#      y       3.50
#Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

Once `observed=True` is specified, this gives a result similar to the non-category output, so the `transform` seems to proceed as expected.

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], observed=True)['col3'].median()
#col1  col2
#a     w       2.65
#b     x       2.40
#c     y       3.50
#Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

Comment: `as_index=False`, does not return the same, but does remove the NaN values

Comment: why the modification in latest version of pandas? used to work without this in previous version

Comment: @rock321987 probably related to `Bug in Series.groupby() where observed kwarg was previously ignored (GH24880)` which was updated in 0.25.0

Comment: found your comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559298/pandas-0-25-0-groupby-on-categoricals

Comment: seems like the [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24880) was closed.. but this problem still exists..

Comment: @rock321987 if you happened to file new issue please link it